# magento 2 how to get shipping method in system configuration

Tags: shipping, system.xml

system.xml

```
<field id="shippingmethod" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Shipping Method</label>
                <depends>
                    <field id="restrictpaymentbyship/general/enable">1</field>
                </depends>
                <source_model>Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allmethods</source_model>
            </field>
```

Comment: you can use helper for that

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper function for that like this

```
public function isB2bRfqFormEnable()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('requestforquote/general/enable-rfq-form', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }
```

this your **requestforquote/general/enable-rfq-form** `sectionid/groupid/fieldid`

Now Just Inject this helper where ever you want like this

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $helper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Netsmartz\RequestForQuote\Helper\Data');
            if($helper->isB2bRfqFormEnable())

            {
                 if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {        
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
            $url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('requestforquote/index/index');
            $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
            return $this;  
        }
        else{
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
            $url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('customer/account/create');
            $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
            return $this;
        }

            }
    }
```

see here am checking if that field is enabled

```
$helper = 

    \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Netsmartz\RequestForQuote\Helper\Data');
                    if($helper->isB2bRfqFormEnable())

                            {
                              //and then you code here
                            }
```

Hope this helps